# Cases when stress has to be moved to preposition

Tags: предлоги, ударение

In Polish language in some combination containing prepositions, stress is moved from following word on the preposition - for example, **na** nas.

A couple of days ago I've been thinking about this fact and suddenly realize that actually in Russian out of my head I can name following cases when stress is moved on the preposition (excuse me for obscene lexicon, think of following phrases from the heights of pure linguistics interest):

> - *на́ хуй*
> - *на́ фиг*
> - *на́ хрен*
> - *на́ кол* (but *на ко́л* is also acceptable)
> - *на́ пол* (but *на по́л* is also acceptable)

At the same time, you can not say *н́а вас, н́а нас*. At the same time, there is only one option in phrases *на хуя, на хрена*, i.e. stressing the last syllable.

It got even more complicated when I realize that, for native speaker phrase, once again, sorry for cursing, *На́ хуй ты уронил ящик на ху́й?* is totally valid, though situation described in phrase is quite unrealistic :)

So, my question is: When should I and when shouldn't I move stress to the preposition?

Comment: Я не знаю, почему это так, но могу предложить дополнительные примеры:
на́ душу (не хочу брать грех на душу); на́ голову (слаб на голову). Больше ходовых выражений с ударением на "на" в русском языке придумать не могу.

Comment: @user750 отличные дополнения, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before XVI, it was a norm for nouns with accentual paradigm `c` to shift the stress onto prepositions: *бе́з мужа, о́ мирѣ, на́ гробъ* etc.

In the modern language, only some of those nouns still shift the stress (including those you mentioned, also *нос, голова, стена* and several others); however, the rules are quite complex and not stable: for instance, both *за го́лову* and *за́ голову* are possible.

There is a whole chapter 3.48 in Zaliznyak's *От праславянской акцентуации к русской* about this phenomenon.

Comment: this is only part of the picture, it's not only about stability - as I've already mentioned на хуй (why) and "на хуй" (literal meaning). Compare "по рублю на нос" and "капля упала на нос". But this is a very nice answer indeed. Now I know why we say (без году неделя).

Comment: @shabunc "нахуй", "нафиг" are adverbs, not nouns. I even doubt you coreectly spelled them with a space.

Comment: @Anixx: the literary norm for those has not settled yet, but generally, the adverbial clauses merge into adverbs only if the noun has lost the form and the adverbial cannot be perceived as a grammatical phrase anymore. Compare *наспех / на смех*, *замуж / в жёны* etc. This is not the case for those. See Rosenthal, *СПС, § 56. Слитное написание наречий*

Comment: @Quassnoi Anyway the dictionary says it is an adverb or pronoun even if a compound http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_7915 that means the "на" is not a preposition here any more.

Comment: @Anixx, the gist of the question is about how we should stress tis word combination, so, actually, in this particular case it is not that important how we treat this phrase from the grammatical point of view.

Comment: @Anixx: FWIW, *местоим. нареч.* means "pronominal adverb", not "adverb or pronoun" :)

Comment: @Quassnoi ok :-)

Comment: I'll count this an answer, since it looks like nothing more relevant will be provided by anybody. At least you've referenced quite interesting book. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

В таких выражениях ударение на предлог ставится из-за того, что они образуют устойчивые выражения и постепенно превращаются в наречия. Например, в приведённой выше фразе про ящик я бы, как носитель языка, написал скорее так:

> Нахуй ты уронил ящик на хуй?

Хотя ваш вариант тоже правильный, просто тут нет устоявшихся норм языка из-за того, что данное выражение табуировано.

То есть все эти случаи - это исключения, в которых ударение закрепилось на предлоге из-за того, что предлог со словом образуют устойчивую конструкцию с особым значением и, в большей или меньшей степени, готовы образовать наречие.

Из примеров могу ещё припомнить такие выражения, в которых допустимо ударение на предлог *на*:

> на́ день
>
> на́ год
>
> на́ борт

Comment: про табуированность - не совсем так. Из табуированности далеко не всегда следует отсутствие норм правописания. Кроме того, уже упомянутые и вполне себе приличные "на нос" и "на душу" не пишутся слитно, хотя, в зависимости от контекста, произносятся и так, и так.